# Ruby - Why does this minor function change result in a big time difference?

Tags: ruby, performance

This script is for Project Euler [#14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14)

I am refactoring it and all I did was grab 1 line of code `n.even? ? n = n/2 : n = (3*n) + 1` and made it into it's own function. This change increase the execution time by 5 seconds.

Why would that happen?

Before:

```
def longest_collatz_sequence1(count)
  check = []
  while count >= 1
    n = count
    seq = [count]
    while n > 1
      n.even? ? n = n/2 : n = (3*n) + 1
      seq << n
    end
    count -= 1
    check << seq
    value = sequence_check(check) if check.length == 2
  end
  puts "The number that produces the largest chain is: #{value[0][0]}"
end

def sequence_check(check)
  check[0].length > check[1].length ? check.delete_at(1) : check.delete_at(0)
  check
end

s = Time.new
longest_collatz_sequence1 1000000
puts "elapsed: #{Time.new-s}"
#~12.2 seconds
```

After:

```
def longest_collatz_sequence1(count)
  check = []
  while count >= 1
    n = count
    seq = [count]
    while n > 1
      n=collatz(n)
      seq << n
    end
    count -= 1
    check << seq
    value = sequence_check(check) if check.length == 2
  end
  puts "The number that produces the largest chain is: #{value[0][0]}"
end

def collatz(n)
  n.even? ? n = n/2 : n = (3*n) + 1
end
def sequence_check(check)
  check[0].length > check[1].length ? check.delete_at(1) : check.delete_at(0)
  check
end

s = Time.new
longest_collatz_sequence1 1000000
puts "elapsed: #{Time.new-s}"
#~17.7 seconds
```

Comment: Does ruby have call-by-reference? If a function changes its argument, the change is not seen outside unless it has call-by-reference.

Comment: Method calls aren't free. You're calling a method 131 million times. It adds up.

Comment: BTW, timing a single run can be very misleading. You'd be better off using [`Benchmark`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) from the standard library and looking at a couple thousand runs.

Comment: Everything in Ruby is an object.  there are no primitives. So every operation is a method call, including +, -, *, and /.  My guess, and this is only a guess, is that ruby has to branch forward, load and byte convert your separate method and then branch back.. The first time you do this there is likely some measurable amount of overhead that subsequent iterations will avoid.  But, it is only a guess.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: No, Ruby is strictly call-by-value, just like Smalltalk, Python, ECMAScript, Java, C, etc.